# Is there a way to change tkcalendar's color?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

I'm trying to make tkcalendar blend in with my window.

```
import tkinter
from tkcalendar import Calendar



window = tkinter.Tk()
window.configure(background = "black")



cal = Calendar(window, background = "black" , disabledbackground = "black" , borderbackground = "black" , headersbackground = "black" , normalbackground = "black" )
cal.config(background = "black")
cal.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

I've read through the tkcalendar documentation and tried changing all the style elements by calling the configure method of widget class :

```
cal.configure(background = "black")
```

; however, my calendar still remains gray instead of blending into the black window background. Is it possible to change the actual background color of the calendar?

[image]

Comment: As far as i know : tkcalendar is a widget. And in the documentation it says that it inherits from all the widgets methods of tkinter. So change cal.config to cal.configure and it should do the trick

Comment: @yAzou I tried that and no luck there. It only changes the little arrow colors

Comment: okay, i edit your post to add that you also tired to call the inherited method `configure` of widget...it should be useful for who will read your post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing it the right way, except that OSX default theme does not support changing background colors (it is based on pictures I think so you can only change the text color).
The solution is to use a different ttk theme (e.g. clam or alt):

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import Calendar

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.configure(background = "black")

style = ttk.Style(window)
style.theme_use('clam')   # change theme, you can use style.theme_names() to list themes

cal = Calendar(window, background="black", disabledbackground="black", bordercolor="black", 
               headersbackground="black", normalbackground="black", foreground='white', 
               normalforeground='white', headersforeground='white')
cal.config(background = "black")
cal.pack()
```

By the way, the option 'borderbackground' does not exists, the correct name is 'bordercolor'.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Any option to change the font color?

Comment: @CoolCloud The font of which part? Because you can change separately the font color of the month and year, of the header, of normal days, of week-end days, .... It's all written in the [documentation](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Calendar.html#class)

Answer (score 0):

The `Calendar` class in `tkcalendar` module is a [subclass of `ttk.Frame`](https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar/blob/master/tkcalendar/calendar_.py#L41).

```
class Calendar(ttk.Frame):
```

You must use the [styling specific to ttk](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/48.md) that uses themes to alter its attributes.

Comment: Thank you, but how would I use this to change the color? I'm very new to tkinter