# How to change button colours of Calendar widget of tkcalendar?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, calendar, tkcalendar

I am able to customize colours of all portions of the Calendar except for its buttons.

[image: Image of Customized Calendar here]

How can I customize colours for the buttons too?

I read through the documentation to change the colours but I could not find how to customize the buttons.

Update: Was able to make the buttons more visually appealing by changing the style theme to 'clam', but extensive customization is still not possible.

Screenshot New calendar image:

[image: New calendar image]

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61493630/is-there-a-way-to-change-tkcalendars-color

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @toyota Supra Yes, I was able to change the button colour so that its more visually appealing when I changed the theme to 'clam', but extensive customization of the button is still not possible.

Comment: Thankyou @toyota Supra for helping!

Comment: It is my pleasure to help.

Comment: The buttons are instances of `ttk.Button()` and linked with style `"L.<name of calendar instance>.TButton"` (left arrow) and `"R.<name of calendar instance>.TButton"` (right arrow) where `<name of calendar instance>` is the result of `str(cal)` (`cal` is the instance of calendar).  So you can configure those styles to change the color of the buttons.